# How does the XE predicate work out the AND OR without any brackets?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I have the following XE predicate examples:

Sample 1:

```
Duration>1000000
AND cputime>1000
OR logicalreads>25000
```

Sample 2:

```
Duration>1000000
OR cputime>1000
AND logicalreads>25000
```

I understand it does short circuit but how does it work out the logic without the presence of brackets?

For sample 1 is it:

```
(A and B) or C
A and (B or C)
```

For sample 2 is it:

```
A or (B and C)
(A or B) and C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make us of the Operator Precedence. `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`, so will be evaluated first.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

So in your examples it will be, for sample 1

```
(A and B) or C
```

And of sample 2

```
A or (B and C)
```

And the one from the comments:

```
A and B or C and D
```

Will be handled as

```
(A and B) or (C and D)
```

Comment: How about `A and B or C and D`. Does this get treated as `(A and B) or (C and D)`?

Comment: Or is it like `A and (B or (C and D))`

Comment: added it in the answer